# do i able to run exec() on queue jobs for laravel

Tags: php, laravel

now im doing laravel project and i want to run a command `exec()` on queue jobs. the Question is, do i really can run the command `exec()` on queue jobs?

this what i've done, i create a jobs file call `app/Jobs/GetData.php` and create a simple code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class GetData implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $csvFileName = public_path("csv/nintendo.csv");

        $process = exec('facebook-scraper --filename '.$csvFileName.' --pages 1 '.$this->record->facebook_id);

    }
}
```

but not success to run the exec().. if i implement this code on controller file. i can success to run the command and download the .CSV file.

before i tried to use this

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
 -----

        $csvFileName = public_path("csv/nintendo.csv"); 

        $process = new Process("facebook-scraper --filename ".$csvFileName." --pages 5 nintendo");
        $process->run();

        // executes after the command finishes
        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            //execute failed code
        }else{
            //execute success code
        }
        $process->getOutput();
```

but this also not working.. please help how to execute the command inside the queue jobs on laravel.

Comment: Did you try by passing the full path of facebook-scraper?

Comment: nice!!! it works!! thank you @SachinKumar

Comment: Welcome @ferdinand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue of non working command you have to either create env variables which points to Facebook-scraper or use the full path(absolute not relative) of facebook scraper package.

So the process construction should be something like

```
$process = new Process("/full-path/of/facebook-scraper --filename ".$csvFileName." --pages 5 nintendo");

$process->run();
```